# What is the difference of friend iterator and friend class iterator which encounter in thinking in c++?

Tags: c++, friend, friend-class

In Thinking in C++ Volume 1, chapter 16: Introduction to Templates. 
The context:

> Notice that instead of just saying:

```
friend iterator; // Make it a friend
```

> This code has:

```
friend class iterator; // Make it a friend
```

> This is important because the name "iterator" is already in scope, from an included file.

What does Eckel really mean above?
It seems `friend iterator` compiles correctly and I can't see the differences. Can anyone tell the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As per C++03 standard section 11.4:

***An elaborated-type-specifier shall be used in a friend declaration for a class.***

So as per the specification the compiler will warn you that the friend declaration of `iterator` must be an elaborated class name. If not then the complier is non-compliant to the standard in this particular aspect.

What are ***Elaborated Type Specifiers***?
C++ use elaborated type specifiers to tell the compiler explicitly to treat a class as a class.  I think MSDN can explain it much better than I can, So check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f432x8c6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) out for detailed explanation.

Comment: Maybe an explanation on what `elaborated type specifier` means, because y'know, standardese isn't for everyone. :)

Comment: @Xeo: Added a link to MSDN, I hope that shall suffice.:)

Comment: Also, in C++0x this restriction is lifted for template parameters, so we can now have `template<class D> class Final{ friend D; ~Final(){} };`.